# ¿Cuál es la diferencia de invocar un método del JDK por medio de la importación y de invocarlo por medio de una declaración?¿Es uno más recomendable?

Tags: java, java-import

Aquí tengo dos objetos de la clase DecimalFormat: as y df. A 'as' lo estoy llamando a travez de su import y a 'df' como si fuese una variable.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ExperimentosGUI {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat as = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    double b = 123.1232434;

    System.out.println(df.format(b));
    System.out.println(as.format(b));
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

El `import` no hace nada en tiempo de ejecución.

Lo único que hace es indicarle al compilador que las referencias a la clase `DecimalFormat` son en realidad a la clase `java.util.DecimalFormat`, y te permite escribir el nombre "corto" en vez de todo el nombre jerárquico.

Las dos variables son idénticas, de hecho si no lo fueran no podrías asignar una instancia de `DecimalFormat` a un `java.text.DecimalFormat`.